# Emit Events To Socket.IO Not Working From Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i am trying to get a chat program to work using socket.io but it doesnt seem to work properly.

i am using a Node.js server and it seems to be running properly. i think this may have something to do with emitting to rooms.

the code i have on the client browser is:

```
<script>

   var socket = io("https://localhost:3000/userChat");
   socket.on('connect', function(){ 
     socket.emit('initialiseConnection', "user1");
   });

   socket.on('messageIn', function(msg){
     console.log(msg);
     $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg.message));
   });

</script>
```

so when the page loads, socket.io it connects to the server and emits the "initialiseConnection" event on the server with "user1". which is a new room specifically for that user.

on the server, the code i have handling "initialiseConnection" is:

```
socket.on("initialiseConnection", function(username){
    socket.join(username);
    console.log(username + " has joined.");

    Message.find({recipient:username}, function (err, message){
       console.log("messages for "+username+": "+message.length);
       for (var x = 0; x < message.length; x++){
         console.log(username+"'s message "+x);
         console.log(message[x]);

         socket.to(username).emit("messageIn", {"message":message[x]});
       }
    });
});
```

this code as you can see, creates and joins a room with the same name as the username. the looks in the database for any messages, and tries to emit those messages to the user. i log the message. there is definately a message and the username in the "socket.to()" method is also correctly shown in the logs. but the "socket.on('messageIn')" on the client browser doesnt seem to be picking up the event.

i have also tried putting:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  socket.to(username).emit("messageIn", {"message":"test message"});
}, 5000);
```

immediately after the socket.join(), in case this was related to some backbround processing that needed to complete

can anyone see where i may have gone wrong on this?

Thanks.

--EDIT 1--------------------------------------

```
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = https.createServer(https_options, app).listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var userChat = io.of("/userChat");
userChat.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on("initialiseConnection", function(username){
     ...
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    socket.leave(socket.room);
  });
});
```

Comment: Where's the other part of the server-side code that listens for connect events and then binds the event handler to each incoming socket?  Since you didn't include that, I'm wondering if that's where the issue is.

Comment: i've added a cut down version in the EDIT 1. let me know if you need more. although i would have though if it is able to connect in one direction. communication in the opposite direction would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
socket.to(username).emit("messageIn", {"message":message[x]});
```

to this:

```
socket.emit("messageIn", {"message":message[x]});
```

A socket is the endpoint.  When sending, you just send directly to the socket.  You don't send to a user in a room?  You just send to a socket.  Since you already have the socket in your `socket` variable, that's what you send to.

Comment: thanks this seems to be the solution. i though i would have to be in a room in order to emit an event to it.

Comment: @X0r0N - rooms are ONLY a grouping of sockets that allows the library to support sending the same message to everyone in the group (or everyone except the original sender).  Internally, the engine always sends a given message for a given recipient to an actual socket.  Thus, if you know which user you want to send it to, you just send to that user's socket.